# Remove string before comma in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field which is in this format:

```
value 1, description
```

What I am trying to do is to update this column by keep only the description part and remove the value 1.

Example of what I have in my field:

```
1st district, Rockville
6th district, Gaithersburg / Montgomery Village
```

What I want to have after update:

```
Rockville
Gaithersburg / Montgomery Village
```

Now I use this but it gives me the first part instead of second:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN INSTR(field, ',') > 0
        THEN substr(field, 1, instr(field, ',') +1)
        ELSE myfield
    END) AS myfield
FROM
    mydata
```

Comment: What if there is more than one comma in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the position of `comma` as start position of `substr` function instead of substring length

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN INSTR(field, ',') > 0
        THEN substr(field, instr(field, ',') +1)
        ELSE myfield
    END) AS myfield
FROM
    mydata
```

As mentioned in comments it can be simplified to

```
SELECT substr(field, instr(field, ',') +1) AS myfield
FROM   mydata
```

To update

```
update mydata Set field = substr(field, instr(field, ',') +1)
Where instr(field, ',') > 1
```

Comment: Case is not required. as instr will return 0 if `,` is not present

Comment: The select works just fine, how can i make the update command?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) here. Something like:

```
substr(regexp_substr(field, ',[^,]+'),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to get the part after the last comma, you can do this:

Using `SUBSTR` + `INSTR`:

```
select 
  trim(substr(field,instr(field,',',-1)+1))
from mydata;
```

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
select 
  trim(regexp_substr(field,'[^,]+$'))
from mydata;
```

TRIM is used to remove any redundant leading or trailing whitespace left in the string.